# GDI+ Error while UnlockBits

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+, aforge, template-matching

I am trying to find a image within an image (Template matching) with the AForge library.

```
                ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.921f);
                // find all matchings with specified above similarity

                TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(dest.Bitmap, oI.Bitmap);
                // highlight found matchings

                BitmapData data = dest.Bitmap.LockBits(
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, dest.Bitmap.Width, dest.Bitmap.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, dest.Bitmap.PixelFormat);
                List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
                foreach (TemplateMatch m in matchings)
                {
                    points.Add(new Point(m.Rectangle.X, m.Rectangle.Y));

                }
                dest.Bitmap.UnlockBits(data); << Error
```

However I get an `GDI+ Exception`

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
Generic GDI+ Exception.
```

(This code was copied from the TemplateMatching example [here](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/17494328-ef0c-dc83-1bc3-907b7b75039f.htm))

Note: This code snippet is running within a `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: Not really clear. Why are locking that bitmap in memory and then, from this code, you're doing nothing with it? There are some parts missing.

Comment: Yeeah... as it is shown, that whole operation is useless. Give more info on what actually happens.